# RESTful HTTP call from Android

Tags: android, restful-authentication

I've been trying to make a RESTful POST call from an Android app for several days now. I've tried a number of different methods and I haven't had any luck so far. There seem to be several issues, Firstly I added

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to the manifest to ensure I could work with sockets/network.

Then I've tried the following different methods to try and get a call out:

```
    System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
 HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url+mUrl).openConnection();
 c.setUseCaches(false);
 c.setDoOutput(true);
 c.setRequestMethod("POST");
 c.setRequestProperty("Content-length","9");
 c.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 c.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
 c.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "basic " + Base64.encodeBytes((username+":"+password).getBytes()));
 c.connect();
 OutputStream os = c.getOutputStream();
 os.write("mode=Push".getBytes());
 os.flush();
 os.close();
```

I'm not sure if Android automatically deals with any required proxy settings, I tried adding that in but in this method the c.connect() just hangs forever, no exception, no timeout, no return.

The next method was as follows:

```
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = getClient();
 HttpResponse response = null;  
 HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(this.url + mUrl);
 postMethod.addHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 postMethod.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
 postMethod.addHeader("Authorization", "basic " + Base64.encodeBytes((username+":"+password).getBytes()));

 if (hm == null) return null;  
 try 
 {  
  List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
  Iterator<String> it = hm.keySet().iterator();  
  String k, v;  
  while (it.hasNext()) 
  {  
   k = it.next();  
   v = hm.get(k);  
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(k, v));  
  }  
  postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  
  response = httpClient.execute(postMethod);
```

This now either returns UnknownHostException when I run it from work, behind a proxy/firewall or when I run it from home then I get a Challenge empty exception.
This is all running under the emulator, Droid 1.6 app. I've got Fiddler2 running and I'm not seing anything coming out over port 80 at all... Help :)

Comment: Quick question: new HttpPost(this.url + mUrl) looks a bit fishy. What are url and mUrl set to?

Comment: url is the base for the api and mURl is just the relative part .. so it would be "http://api.xyz.com/serviceX/method";

Comment: I've managed to get BOTH of the above methods working via emulator from my home connection. I think now the only issue is to do with firewall/proxy from our work network. Are any settings in the emulator I need to be aware of, or something I should add the code to specify a proxy?